Potential ground loop issue in DC-DC common ground circuit
I am trying to setup a dedicated battery for my dash-camera, this will provide continuous power when the ignition is OFF and has a manual NC switch to turn off the circuit when not needed.

I connected this to my car, while trying to start the car the ignition motor won't crank, looks like it drained my battery or a fuse is blown. (not really sure of this, since I was working with reading lamps turned on for quite sometime).
Here, the thyristor acts as a manual cut off switch, when the vehicle is parked for long duration. It turns on (supply to gate) when there is ignition and keeps the circuit from the dedicated battery to the hardwire kit closed even when ignition is off (this is to turn on parking mode). Until the NC switch is pressed, breaking the connection turns off the supply from battery.
My concern is the shared common ground, because when the ignition is off, the dedicated battery might power the device, which could potentially supply a reverse current to car's electrical system or is there a ground loop.
I need to diagnose this, how do I approach this? what am I missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Update:
I have modified the circuit like this:

this is working when tested with AC-DC adapter yet to test in car, turns out battery drain was the issue (Do not keep your reading lamps on, when vehicle is off).
If I try this with the car, will this work without any issue?

What is the thyristor doing in this circuit?

@bobflux I have edited the question, please check. thanks

OK I see. But you do have a ground loop that keeps your device powered... or at least "something" powered... you should interrupt the positive, not the negative

@bobflux When I tried to interrupt the positive, the device is not turning on, I tested with a 12v AC- DC adapter. The above circuit work fine, in the car... problem.
PS: I also not sure what caused, for my car to not turn on, I think it is battery drain. but could be a fuse blown, or any other. If you can identify the potential issue, that could be much helpful.

What's the difference between the red and yellow wires? I can't make sense of the schematic since they look connected but the yellow has a different label

Yellow is ACC, Red is battery.

OK so the buck boost and ammeter are powered all the time even when ignition is off? That could drain your car's battery

Sorry for misunderstanding, buck boost and ammeter will only get power when ignition ON.
